# python compare strings return difference

Tags: python, string, difference

Consider this sample data:

```
str_lst = ['abcdefg','abcdefghi']
```

I am trying to write a function that will compare these two strings in this list and return the difference, in this case, 'hi'

This attempt failed and simply returned both strings.

```
def difference(string1, string2):
    # Split both strings into list items
    string1 = string1.split()
    string2 = string2.split()

    A = set(string1) # Store all string1 list items in set A
    B = set(string2) # Store all string2 list items in set B
 
    str_diff = A.symmetric_difference(B)
    # isEmpty = (len(str_diff) == 0)
    return str_diff
```

There are several SO questions claiming to seek this, but they simply return a list of the letters that differ between two strings where, in my case, the strings will have many characters identical at the start and I only want the characters near the end that differ between the two.

Ideas of how to reliably accomplish this?  My exact situation would be a list of very similar strings, let's say 10 of them, in which I want to use the first item in the list and compare it against all the others one after the other, placing those differences (i.e. small substrings) into a list for collection.

I appreciate you taking the time to check out my question.

Some hypos:

The strings in my dataset would all have initial characters identical, think, directory paths:

```
sample_lst = ['c:/universal/bin/library/file_choice1.zip', 
'c:/universal/bin/library/file_zebra1.doc',
'c:/universal/bin/library/file_alpha1.xlsx']
```

Running the ideal function on this list would yield a list with the following strings:

```
result = ['choice1.zip', 'zebra1.doc', 'alpha1.xlsx']
```

Thus, these are the strings that remaining when you remove any duplicate characters at the start of all of the three lists items in sample_lst

Comment: str_lst = ['defg','abcdefghi']     what output do you want here? Only "hi"? or "abchi"?     will all the characters in string2 contain all the characters in string1?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want either. If you had two strings "abccc" and "abbbc" what should the "difference" between them be?

Comment: share some more example so that question will be more clear..

Comment: What did you expect `string1 = string1.split()` to do? Try printing each variable after each line (or use a debugger) and see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after you have provided some additional clarification I think I understand what you are looking for. Thanks. So I think that I would break the problem into two steps :

1. Find the longest common initial substring of your input strings
2. Find the "remainder" of each string after removing the longest common
   initial substring.

```
def updateCommonInitialSubstring(s,t):
    nchars = min(len(s), len(t))
    for i in range(nchars):
        if s[i] != t[i]:
            return s[:i]
    return s[:nchars]
    
def findLongestCommonInitialSubstring(strings):
    common = strings[0]
    for s in strings[1:]:
        common = updateCommonInitialSubstring(common, s)
    return common 

def findDistinctSuffixes(strings):
    # Find the longest common substring of the strings.
    common = findLongestCommonInitialSubstring(strings)
    # Find the distinct suffixes of the common substring.
    suffixes = []
    for s in strings:
        suffixes.append(s[len(common):])
    return suffixes
```

With this implementation the following test case passes:

```
def test_findDistinctSuffixes2():
    # Arrange
    sample_lst = ['c:/universal/bin/library/file_choice1.zip', 
                  'c:/universal/bin/library/file_zebra1.doc',
                  'c:/universal/bin/library/file_alpha1.xlsx']    
    # Act
    result = findDistinctSuffixes(sample_lst)
    # Assert
    assert result == ['choice1.zip', 'zebra1.doc', 'alpha1.xlsx']
```

which is what I think that you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution.
This doesn't take into account if there are multiple occurrences of the same character in the given string i.e., the frequency is ignored and gives output string made up of characters that are different and present in only one of the two strings.

```
if(len(s) < len(t)):
   s, t = t, s
   diff = ""
   for i in s:
      if(i not in t):
         diff += i
   return diff
```

Example1 :-

```
#input
s = "abcd"
t = "dcabhi"

#output
diff = "hi"
```

Example2 :-

```
#input
s = "abcd"       #occurence of a = 1
t = "dcaabhi"    #occurence of a = 2

#output
diff = "hi"
```

Complex solution. This solution keeps count of the the number of occurrences i.e., the frequency of characters is taken into consideration.

```
s_hash = {}
t_hash = {}
for i in s:
   if(i not in s_hash):
      s_hash[i] = 1
   else:
      s_hash[i] += 1    
for i in t:
   if(i not in t_hash):
      t_hash[i] = 1
   else:
      t_hash[i] += 1
for i in t_hash:
   if(i in s_hash and (s_hash[i] != t_hash[i])):
      return i
   elif(i not in s_hash):
      return i
```

Example1 :-

```
#input
s = "abcd"
t = "dcabhi"

#output
diff = "hi"
```

Example2 :-

```
#input
s = "abcd"     #occurence of a = 1
t = "dcaahi"   #occurence of a = 2

#output
diff = "ahi"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).